# How to remove all elements from JPanel in super class using Action Listener in subclass?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, subclass, actionlistener

I'm new to Java so please help :)
I have one super class called **MainFrame**  with main method and constructor class **Run()**. 
I get menubar for JFrame from subclass caled **MenuBar**. **Menu bar** has multiple subclasses with implemented ActionListeners. 
I have been getting an error whenever I try to use ActionListener to call a method from **MainFrame** superclass that removes all elements from **JPanel** that is initialized in **MainFrame** constructor method **Run()**
Code for MainFrame:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;


public class MainFrame {
    JFrame mainFrame;
    JPanel mainPanel;
    JPanel[] pagePanels, tablePanels;
    JScrollPane scrollBar;

    private double zoom=1;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private GridBagConstraints c;

    //private Page blankPage = new Page();
    MenuBar menubar;
    Page blankPage;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame generator = new MainFrame();
        generator.Run();
    }

    public void Run() {

        pagePanels = new JPanel[100];
        tablePanels = new JPanel[100];

        menubar = new MenuBar();
        blankPage = new Page();
        c = new GridBagConstraints();

        mainFrame = new JFrame("Code Generator v.1.0");
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        c.gridx=0;
        c.insets = new Insets(20,0,20,0);
        //get size of screen
        GetScreenSize();

        mainPanel=new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        scrollBar=new JScrollPane(mainPanel);
        scrollBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));

        //create main frame with height and width equal to screen size (fullscreen)
        mainFrame.setJMenuBar(menubar.getMenuBar());
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(scrollBar);
        mainFrame.setSize(width,height);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void GetScreenSize(){
        GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
        width = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
        height = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
    }

    public void RemoveAllfromMainPanel(){
        mainPanel.removeAll();
    }


}
```

Code for subclass **MenuBar** is:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MenuBar  extends MainFrame{

    public JMenuBar getMenuBar(){

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();

        //add menus to menu bar 
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        menubar.add(file);

        //add items to File menu
        JMenuItem newReport = new JMenuItem("New report");
        file.add(newReport);
        newReport.addActionListener(new newReport());

        JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        file.add(exit);
        exit.addActionListener(new exitAction());

        return menubar;

    }

    class exitAction implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    class newReport implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            RemoveAllfromMainPanel();
        }
    }
}
```

I think that it has to do something with inheritance but that is the topic that I have recently started to study. Can you please explain to me why am i getting this error:

**Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MainFrame.TEST(MainFrame.java:125)**

at this line:

**mainPanel.removeAll();**

Thank you in advance! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MenuBar` shouldn't be extending from `MainFrame`.  This is not the same instance that is created by your run method from your `main` method, meaning that `mainPanel` has not yet being initialised.

Instead, you should be passing `MenuBar` a refernce of an instance of `MainFrame` when you create it

```
    menubar = new MenuBar(this);
```

And on you MenuBar...

```
public class MenuBar {

    private MainFrame mainFrame;

    public MenuBar(MainFrame mainFrame) {
        this.mainFrame = mainFrame;
    }

    /* other code */


    class newReport implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            mainFrame.RemoveAllfromMainPanel();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: This works! Thank you very much for quick response!
My original idea was to do something like this but I didn't quite know how :) Well, now I know :)

Answer (score 1):

You actually have two different instances, and that is the problem here.

First, when you start the application, you create a `MainFrame` object and call `Run` on that instance (please use lower case names for methods). That instances has a properly initialized field `mainPanel`.

Then you create a second instance of `MenuBar`, a class that extends `MainFrame`.  It inherits the the fields from the superclass but **not** the values from the other instance. So the `MenuBar` object has a `mainPanel` field too but that is `null`. Now, when you call `RemoveAllfromMainPanel()` on the menuBar, you access the field from the menuBar instance and call `removeAll` on `null` which causes the NPE.

Comment: thanks for your explanation! I'm new to Java and explanations like this are very valuable. I appreciate it! Cheers :)